# PhpStorm typed variable alignment

Tags: formatting, phpstorm

I haven't found any good resources for this, so here's the question.
I have the following code:

```php
public function myFunction(
    string $name,
    int $age
) {}
```

When I format the code, PhpStorm will align the variables like so:

```php
public function myFunction(
    string $name,
    int    $age
) {}
```

I want to STOP this behaviour and have it format the code like the first block. Running build `#PS-213.7172.28` in case that matters.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting this correctly: it is introduced by [WI-59669](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59669) in PhpStorm 2021.2.3.

Here is a [WI-61085](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-61085) ticket that asks to have such double alignment (by both type and parameter name) optional -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.